# Angular4 search Error as it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText); is not function

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

Here i wrote simple search function its throughing an Error as  it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);

**Search code**

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    debuger;
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
      return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
}
```

**Table**

```
    <input [(ngModel)]="searchText" placeholder="enter search term here">
<table  class="table table-sm">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Auction ID</th>
                        <th>Auction Name</th>
</thead>
                    <tbody>

               <tr *ngFor="let value of auction?.data | filter :searchText">
<tr>
                        <th>Auction ID</th>
                        <th>Auction Name</th>
                       <tr/>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Did you try to debug in the pipe ?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara its throughing an Errror as  it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText); is not function

Comment: Can you add the error to the question?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara  sorry for the mistake can i know wat mistake im foing

Comment: what does **auction?.data** include?

Comment: @JpDuminy Put a `console.log('it: ', it);` before `return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);` to debug and see what value has `it`.

Comment: auction.data i change it

Comment: i make this cange its working           return it.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);

Comment: use if (!items || items.lenght<=0) return []